# Android Application not installed error

Tags: android, build, android-gradle-plugin, android-install-apk

I have created one application in `AndroidStudio` ,I used my Sony mobile as a `ADB`. The Application works fine in my mobile, also I generated the signed `APK` but the problem is when i try to install that it says, application not installed.Then I tried with my friend mobile it remains the same.we are using the same `SDK` OS.Currently am using Android studio 2.3 version.I have tried the build `gradle` method also,but not working.Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We had the same problem. When you generate your signed apk you should check the V1(Jar Signature) signature version.

Comment: hey man it works.i just uninstalled the existing app and try to run the new one,it works.sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem And I solved it this way, For Current Updated Android Studio 2.3

Build > Generate Signed apk.
Create Keystore path.
Put Password, alias, key password.
Build type select accordingly(eg to release in playstore use release).
Signature Version select both V1 and V2 checkboxes.
Finsih.
Go to the apk from explorer and use it for your playstore or in devices as Signed and Certified apk file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Android Studio 3.0 then go to Build option and click "Build Apk" option and generate the debug apk first and install it on device.